# Is there any way to save an XmlDocument *without* indentation and line returns?

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument

All my searches have brought up people asking the opposite, but I have a file which grows by nearly 50% if it is saved with line returns and indentation.

Is there any way round this?

**EDIT** I'm not talking about *opening* a file, but *saving* one. This code reproduces the 'bug' for me:

```
var path = @"C:\test.xml";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "<root>\r\n\t<line></line>\r\n\t<line></line>\r\n</root>");
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
doc.Load(path);
doc.PreserveWhitespace = false; //just in case!
doc.Save(path);
```

A breakpoint in the middle shows that doc.InnerXml is effectively `<root><line></line><line></line></root>`, as expected. But the contents of `test.xml` at the end is:

```
<root>
  <line>
  </line>
  <line>
  </line>
</root>
```

Comment: Possible pseudo-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035252/how-to-save-xmldocument-with-multiple-indentation-settings

Comment: (not fully dup/ read vs write - *related* though)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

using(XmlTextWriter wr = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    wr.Formatting = Formatting.None; // here's the trick !
    doc.Save(wr);
}
```

Comment: Woo, and it preserves new lines in `<![CDATA[...]]>` blocks!, thanks

Comment: Thanks! I am currently extracting and importing back data in Trados 2014 (*.sdlxliff) files and they are breaking if i save them without removing the xml formatting.

Answer (score 4):

Use [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
[...]
XmlWriterSettings xwsSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xwsSettings.Indent = false;
xwsSettings.NewLineChars = String.Empty;
using (XmlWriter xwWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\test.xml", xwsSettings))
 xmlDoc.Save(xwWriter);
```

Comment: Note that this also strips new lines from inside `<![CDATA[..]]>` blocks (but not extra spaces).